# Time Manager on LizMap

Tags: time, date, lizmap

We published a project under Ubuntu Server, QGIS, LizMap web client, ..
Everything works except the "time manager".

Under the desktop client, the time manager works correctly (for example
exp: sequences between the dates 2007-01-01 to 2020-06-01) - therefore functional date format.

However, when it is placed on the server in the right place, it does not work and
the dates do not correspond (here 2021-02 -current date/month as start time- to 2021-07).

First, we worked with :

- Lizmap-web-client version is 3.4.1
- This is a shp.
- qgis-server: Installed : 2.18.17+dfsg-1
- Desktop QGIS 3.16
- Fields - we tried many formats (raw data : 2007-01-01 to 2020-06-01)
- Qstring as in the demo  > do not work
- QDate as well yyyy-MM-dd + other date formats as yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00  > do not work
- QDate/Time yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:000. > do not work

To solve the time manager problem, we have installed on another system: ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
qgis-server: 3.10.4 = qgis-dekstop 3.10.4
dfsg-1ubuntu2 (current version of ubuntu repository)
lizmap-web-client 3.4.1.

While running command below i got the error message below. I check, indeed the vendor directory does not exist in this version of the lizmap-web-client. Do you have an idea ?

php lizmap / install / installer.php - PHP Warning: require (/var/www/html/lizmaplive/lizmap/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/lizmaplive/lizmap/application.init.php on line 12

PHP Fatal error: require (): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/lizmaplive/lizmap/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path = '.: / Usr / share / php') in / var / www / html /lizmaplive/lizmap/application.init.php on line 12

if not, can you confirm a qgis-server and lizmap-web-client version that works on a ubuntu server 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Can you add the Lizmap Web Client version ? What is the source of the layer ? A geopackage, shapefile, PG ? Could you press buttons to compute min and max ? What is the description of the field in the "Fields" tab ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. Lizmap Web Client 3.3.6 - this is a shapefile ; I try to change in spatialite but no works - I use 2.18 QGIS Dekstop - so no compute min and max but it works for example on such demo : https://demo.lizmap.com/lizmap/index.php/view/map/?repository=feat1&project=time_manager_earthquake - I try with qgis 3.14 with min and max - and "invalid format" - I change in Qstring as in the example and modify for many date format - yyyy-MM-dd + other date formats as yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 no works - I think it's a detail ...

Comment: Please edit your question for adding new information. It's better than commenting. The time manager changed a lot between Lizmap Web Client (LWC) 3.3 and 3.4. I think you should just upgrade first. Let's check after your field type. You can download the earthquake demo on the link you gave.

Comment: Done but no changes - I add details requested in the question; Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't any update on the Lizmap plugin for QGIS 2 since 2 years. So I really suggest you to switch to QGIS 3. QGIS 2 is end of life since 2 years as well.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of QGIS Server (precisely XX.YY.ZZ) ? Are you switching between QGIS Server 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Only
​​​qgis-server:
   Installed : 2.18.17+dfsg-1

Comment: Ok we will update and try - and also wonder how to display the min and max timestamps on lizmap 3.4 as on the demo - maybe the problem comes from this setting too.

Comment: You must only use the same version between QGIS Desktop and QGIS Server. There is no way QGIS Server 2.18 can read properly a QGIS project made with 3.14. If you switch to QGIS Desktop 3.16, you must upgrade your server to 3.16 as well, it must stay the same version.https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/install/pre_requirements.html#qgis-server Feel free to contact 3liz.com, we can help you on installing your server.

Comment: We updated all as explained in the question - can you confirm this is correct ? or a qgis-server and lizmap-web-client version that works on a ubuntu server 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Which documentation did you follow to install Lizmap Web Client ? The way you downloaded Lizmap is wrong. https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/install/linux.html#with-zip-file It's mentionned to download the ZIP from the release page.

Comment: We used the web-client-lizmap .tgz ; we try the ZIP

Comment: Ok, I understand. It's a pity that we can't remove these automatic asset from GitHub. Only use the ZIP called `lizmap-web-client-.....zip`. Thanks for the feedback. Side note, 3.4.2 will be released monday or tuesday I think.

Comment: Ok, we suspected something - thanks for the information - now, we have qgis server and dekstop 3.10.4 / lizmap 3.4.1 - the demo works and the project seems to work too in its initial version - I keep you informed for the time manager - we'll try now.

Comment: For the time manager - we have this log: ERROR 1: Failed to parse date '1970-01' evaluating OGR WHERE expression. How can I inform Timestamp min and max in Lizmap as in the demo?

Comment: Answering on comments is not designed for that, and not easy. Please check any Lizmap plugin update. Share your field detail, what kind of date format ? What is the file format ? PG ?